# openGL: cannot correctly draw a sphere in front of camera

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw a little sphere in front of the camera, let's say 5 units away (C++, newby in openGL and not very confident in trigonometry!).
I expect that the sphere is always in the middle of my camera when I perform pan and tilt movements.

In my rendering loop, I calculated the coordinates of the sphere in the following way:

```
// 1) settimg my camera
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(camera_angle[1], 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(camera_angle[0], 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(camera_angle[2], 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(camera_pos[0],camera_pos[1],camera_pos[2]);

// 2) retrieving camera pan tilt angles in radians:
double phi  = camera_angle[1] *(M_PI/180.0); //pan
double theta = camera_angle[0] *(M_PI/180.0); //tilt

//3) calculating xyz coordinates of the sphere, if 5 units away from    camera
double dist = -5;
double ax = camera_pos[0] + (-1)*(dist*sin(phi)*cos(theta));
double ay = camera_pos[1] + dist*sin(theta);
double az = camera_pos[2] + dist*cos(theta)*cos(phi);

//4) draw sphere
float ndiv = 2.0;
GLfloat f[]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1};

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(ax, ay, az);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, f);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
makeTri(vdata[tindices[i][0]], vdata[tindices[i][1]], vdata[tindices[i][2]], ndiv, 0.2);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

I found the trigonometric formula here 
[spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates)

Note that I inverted some values like sin and cos, as I guess the correct order depends on reference system (I guess openGL has some inverted axis).

Now I have a strange result, that can be seen in this video:

[sphere behaviour](https://youtu.be/IWB_9HtDkJg)

Please, ignore the coloured spheres in the background and the green square in the middle of the camera, just look at the white sphere in front of the camera.

As you can see, if I perform only pan or only tilt (look at bottom left values showing the exact camera angles), the white sphere is always in the exact centre of the camera, as expected. Nevertheless, when pan and tilt are performed together, the sphere drifts: 
the more pan and tilt values move away from 0 degree, the more the sphere drifts. Moreover, the shape of drift follow a circular trajectory, which is very suspicious for me.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw something that doesn't move relative to the camera you simply start from an identity model-view matrix from scratch:

```
float ndiv = 2.0;
GLfloat f[]={1.0,1.0,1.0,1};

glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();          // <------------- zero out transforms
glTranslated(0, 0, -5);    // <------------- translate 5 units from the camera
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, f);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
makeTri(vdata[tindices[i][0]], vdata[tindices[i][1]], vdata[tindices[i][2]], ndiv, 0.2);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works! Anyway, do you have any idea why my method does not work properly? Am I doing some math wrong?

Comment: @valerio_sperati: I'm sorry but I'm too lazy to check the math :) most probably you just mixed up the order of operations somewhere -- remember that rotation is not commutative, so if openGL rotates first around X then around Y and you do the other way around then you will get different results.

Comment: thanks, you are right! I realised right now that in the very first lines of my code, where I rotate the camera, I called glRotatef() in this (wrong) order: 1,0,2.   Now I corrected the order as 0,1,2 and as result my code works!!! Thanks a lot again